# Php Mysql insert with multiple foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to do an insert where there are FK in a table but it's not working..

My db name is **bd_telefonos**

my db looks like this:

**table marcas**:

> idmarcas --> PK AI
>
> nombre

table **sistemas_operativos**:

> idsistemas_operativos -->PK AI
>
> nombre

table **telefonos**:

> modelo
>
> idtelefonos --> PK AI
>
> resolucion_alto
>
> resolucion_ancho
>
> peso
>
> bateria
>
> marcas_idmarcas --> FK
>
> sistemas_operativos_idsistemas_operativos -- > FK

My php looks like this:

```
<?php
    
include_once('conexion/conexion.php');
$con = new conectar();

$modelo= $_POST['modelo'];
$alto= $_POST['alto'];
$ancho= $_POST['ancho'];
$peso= $_POST['peso'];
$bateria= $_POST['bateria'];
$nombresis = $_POST['nombresis'];
$nombremarca = $_POST['nombremarca'];



$sSql = "INSERT INTO `bd_telefonos`.`telefonos` (`modelo`, `resolucion_alto`, `resolucion_ancho`, `peso`, `bateria`) VALUES ('$modelo', '$alto', '$ancho', '$peso', '$bateria')";

if(!mysqli_query($con->conectarse(), $sSql)){
        $resp = 'error ';


    }
    else{ 

        /*=============================================================================
        =            select recently insert           =
        =============================================================================*/
    
        $sSqlId = "SELECT MAX(id) as `id` FROM `bd_telefonos`.`telefonos`";

        if($respuesta = mysqli_query($con->conectarse(), $sSqlId)){
            foreach ($respuesta as $resp) {
                $id = $resp['id'];
            }
        }
        
        /*========================================================
        =            Insert sistemas_operativos           
        ========================================================*/
        
        $sSqlMas = "INSERT INTO `bd_telefonos`.`sistemas_operativos` (`idsistemas_operativos`, `nombre`) VALUES ('$id', '$nombresis')";

        if (mysqli_query($con->conectarse(), $sSqlMas)) {
            $resp = 'success';
            echo $resp;
        } else {
            $resp = 'error';
            echo $resp;
        }


        /*========================================================
        =            Insert marcas            
        ========================================================*/


        $sSqlMass = "INSERT INTO `bd_telefonos`.`marcas` (`idmarcas`, `nombre`) VALUES ('$id', '$nombremarca')";
        if (mysqli_query($con->conectarse(), $sSqlMass)) {
            $resp = 'success';
            $resp = 'error';

            echo $resp;
        }
        
    }
    
    mysqli_close($con->conectarse());




?>
```

it's not working, it's just not making insert in my table **telefonos** , what am i doing wrong?

help please :(

Comment: "it's not working" is a rather imprecise description of the behavior that is observed. A few suggestions... use `mysqli_error` to retrieve the error message from MySQL, and display the error or log it. Also, the "select max(id)" pattern to retrieve the id value of a row that was just inserted will work in testing, but it's a fundamentally broken pattern with concurrent sessions. The code also appears to be vulnerable to SQL Injection.  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $conn->insert_id rather than MAX(ID).

```
$conn = new mysqli("hostname", "db_user_name", "db_password", "db_name");

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$modelo= $_POST['modelo'];
$alto= $_POST['alto'];
$ancho= $_POST['ancho'];
$peso= $_POST['peso'];
$bateria= $_POST['bateria'];
$nombresis = $_POST['nombresis'];
$nombremarca = $_POST['nombremarca'];



$sSql = "INSERT INTO `telefonos` (`modelo`, `resolucion_alto`, `resolucion_ancho`, `peso`, `bateria`) VALUES ('$modelo', '$alto', '$ancho', '$peso', '$bateria')";

if ($conn->query($sSql) === TRUE) {
    $id = $conn->insert_id;

   /*========================================================
    =            Insert sistemas_operativos
    ========================================================*/

    $sSqlMas = "INSERT INTO `sistemas_operativos` (`idsistemas_operativos`, `nombre`) VALUES ('$id', '$nombresis')";

    if ($conn->query($sSqlMas) === TRUE) {
      echo 'success';
      $sistemas_operativos_id = $conn->insert_id;
    } else {
      echo "Error: " . $sSqlMas . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

   /*========================================================
    =            Insert marcas
    ========================================================*/

    $sSqlMass = "INSERT INTO `marcas` (`idmarcas`, `nombre`) VALUES ('$id', '$nombremarca')";

    if ($conn->query($sSqlMass) === TRUE) {
        echo 'success';
      $marcas_id = $conn->insert_id;
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sSqlMass . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    /************** Update FK ***************/
    $update_sql = "UPDATE telefonos SET marcas_idmarcas ='$marcas_id', sistemas_operativos_idsistemas_operativos ='$sistemas_operativos_id' WHERE idtelefonos = '$id'";
    if ($conn->query($update_sql) === TRUE) {
        echo 'Successfully Update';
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $update_sql. "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }


} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sSql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: I got this error : `Error: INSERT INTO `telefonos` (`modelo`, `resolucion_alto`, `resolucion_ancho`, `peso`, `bateria`) VALUES ('g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g')
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bd_telefonos`.`telefonos`, CONSTRAINT `fk_telefonos_marcas` FOREIGN KEY (`marcas_idmarcas`) REFERENCES `marcas` (`idmarcas`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)`

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to update the below two column in telefonos table

```
marcas_idmarcas --> FK
sistemas_operativos_idsistemas_operativos -- > FK
```

you can get last insert value from both the tables and update in telefonos table